# Is there any way to change a password hint without changing the password?

Tags: macos, password

I have made a typo in my password hint! However, I don't see any way to correct this typo without creating a brand-new password. I don't want to do that either because this is a company computer and the password is managed by the company (and I can't use the same password twice).

**How do I fix the typo in my password hint without changing the whole password?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
dscl . -merge /Users/username hint "your password hint"
```

- Replace `username` with the short name of the account you wish to modify.
- Replace `your password hint` with the hint you would like to set for the account.

`dscl` is the Directory Service command line utility.
`.` is the local machine.
`-merge` allows you to add a new key to a record path.
`/Users/username` is the record path for the key.
`hint` is the key you would like to assign a value.
`your password hint` is the string value for the key.

Comment: Additionally, if you need to use double quotes within your hint, ex: **He's "The Man"**, you would need to delimit the quote characters with backslashes: `dscl . -merge /Users/username hint "He's \"The Man\""`